# How to send data in the mailgun header with LARAVEL?

Tags: laravel, webhooks, mailgun

I am working with webhooks for the first time, in which I have to pass some 3 variables defined for later when Laravel takes it again I can update an action of the email sent for some reports.

The problem is that I can't pass data in the header of the email.

This is the structure that commonly sent the email to the users:

```
public $data;
/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($view, $subject, $data)
{
    $this->view     = $view;
    $this->subject  = $subject;
    $this->data     = $data;
}

public function build()
{
    $message = $this->data;
    // print_r($variables);
    // exit;
    return $this->from(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'))
                ->view($this->view)
                ->subject($this->subject); //WORKED

/**NO WORKED*/
                ->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use ($v){
                    $v->getHeaders()
                    ->addTextHeader('Custom-Header', 'HeaderValue1')
                    ->addTextHeader('Custom-Header2', 'HeaderValue2');
                });
}
```

The emails if sent in that there is no problem, with the view and the data that is filled in the mail, but in the header the data is not filled in at least in this case, the 2 variables set ['Custom-Header', 'HeaderValue1', 'Custom-Header', 'HeaderValue2].

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too and it took me quite a bit of research and testing. It seems that it needs to be in json format and you need to use 'X-Mailgun-Variables' instead of 'Custom-Header'. It should look like this

```
->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Variables', '{"variable1": "1", "variable2": "2"}')
```

the webhook should give you this result

```
  "user-variables":{
     "variable1":"1",
     "variable2":"2"
  },
```